# Difference between the leading eigenvalues of two matrices

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

Suppose we have two real, symmetric and positive semidefinite matrices $A$ and $B$, and we know that they approximate each other well in the sense that

$$\| A - B \|_2 \le \epsilon,$$

where $\epsilon$ is positive and $\|\cdot\|_2$ is the $\ell_2$ operator norm. Is it possible to bound the difference between their leading eigenvalues, $|\lambda_1(A) - \lambda_1(B)|$, in terms of $\epsilon$?

I know it's possible to bound the angle between the leading eigenvectors of $A$ and $B$, but I have no idea how to prove a similar bound for eigenvalues.

Comment: The difference is bound by $\epsilon$ as long as both matrices are normal, see the [Bauer-Fike theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bauer%E2%80%93Fike_theorem#The_Case_of_Normal_Matrices).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We may assume that $\lambda_\max(A)\ge\lambda_\max(B)$. Then
\begin{aligned}
|\lambda_\max(A)-\lambda_\max(B)|
&=\lambda_\max(A)-\lambda_\max(B)\\
&=\|A\|_2-\|B\|_2\\
&\le\|A-B\|_2
\le\epsilon.
\end{aligned}